# Reclassify by remapvalue returns error 000622

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst

I'm trying to reclassify a raster from a set of strings to a set of values. I'm doing this by first creating a RemapValue.

I've added the code I'm trying to run.

```
arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\Users\...\Output\Raster.gdb'

rv = RemapValue([["A1BE", 2],["A1BR", 1],["A1EN", 2]])

reclass = Reclassify("flate2157", "q_type1", rv, "0")
```

When running reclassify it returns two errors:

> 000622: Failed to execute (Reclassify). Parameters are not valid.
>       ERROR 000628: Cannot set input into parameter remap.

I've tried to lookup the help page, but could not get it to work.

Comment: Did you set an environmental work space before these code statements?

Comment: @artwork21 Yes, the correct workspace is set. I cannot understand whats wrong.

Comment: Does flate2157 exist within the Raster.gdb?  Also, does this process work manually using reclassify geoprocessing tool via model builder?  If that works, you could then export out the model to a python script and see how it configures the script/syntax.

Comment: @artwork21 Yes, tried it now. This works fine for one raster. The problem is when I try to do this for more rasters, it will not work. Can it be because some of the reclass values are not in that raster? I have a big reclass file with more than 100 reclassifications, but some of the rasters only have a few (from 5 and upwards) that needs to be reclassified.

Comment: @birks That should not be a problem, reclassify() can accept more keys than are present in the raster. Do you remember what your solution to this was?